# How to normalize a 3-component vector?

Tags: vectors

I know how to normalize a 2 component vector, but I need to normalize a 3-component vector? If it's the same formula as 2-component vector normalization, then how do I figure out the magnitude of a 3-component vector?

Answer (score 3):

It's exactly the same idea: given a non-zero vector $\mathbf{x} = [x_1, x_2, x_3]$, its magnitude is
$$\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}.$$

You normalize $\mathbf{x}$ by dividing by this magnitude. The idea extends to any number of dimensions.

---

Side note: to see why this would be true, imagine the projection $\mathbf{p}$ of $\mathbf{x}$ onto the $x_1,x_2$-plane. The length of that vector is $\Vert \mathbf{p} \Vert = \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$. Now consider the triangle from the origin with $\mathbf{p}$ as a base and extending up to $\mathbf{x}$: its hypotenuse is $\sqrt{\Vert \mathbf{p} \Vert^2 + x_3^2} = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$.

Comment: Quick tip: `\Vert` looks nicer than `||`.

Comment: @K.defaoite I appreciate it! I knew there was a symbol but couldn't remember off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

In 3-dimesnions, $\mathbf{u} = (u_1, u_2, u_3)$, so its $\frac{\mathbb{u}}{\|\mathbb{u}\|}$ where $\|\mathbf{u}\|$ is $\sqrt{u_{1}^1 + u_{2}^2 + u_{3}^2}$

And more generally for a vector $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^n$:
$\|\mathbf{u}\|$ is just $\sqrt{u_{1}^1 + \dots + u_{n}^2}$